# What is power user in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

During one of the calls, I was asked if I had experience  being a "power user" of Kubernetes.
This might be a very basic question but I dint understand it and answered that I was the admin so I had root access. But I am still wondering what exactly does a "power user" in Kubernetes mean?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the term "Power User" refers to someone who is exceptionally fluent in the technology.  This person would be someone others go to for assistance, and routinely solves problems -- often without anyone noticing there was a problem to start with.

It's more about personal work ethic and attributes, not really "experience".

- Proactive
- Postitive
- Solution-oriented
- Helpful
- Efficient
- Enthusiastic

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: It's actually I think a problem that someone asked you that without checking with you that the term is familiar, or digging in deeper when they noticed you were confused.  I hope this wasn't an interview.